# How to pick up a repeating value in an XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML such as:

```
<Response xmlns="www.google.com">
    <Result>
        <Errors xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">

            <a:string>1sterror</a:string>
            <a:string>another error</a:string>
        </Errors>
    </Result>
</Response>
```

I am trying an ouput something like as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pagedata xmlns:aa="www.google.com"
          xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <test>1sterror</test>
   <test>another error</test>
</pagedata>
```

The XSL that i am making is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:aa="www.google.com" 
xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:template match="aa:Response">
<xsl:apply-templates select="aa:Result" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aa:Result">
<pagedata>
<xsl:apply-templates select="aa:Errors"/>
</pagedata>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="aa:Errors">
<xsl:apply-templates select="a:string"/>
</xsl:template>  

<xsl:template match="a:string">
<test>
<xsl:value-of select="a:string"/>
</test>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the output that I am getting is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pagedata xmlns:aa="www.google.com"
          xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <test/>
   <test/>
</pagedata>
```

This is coming without the data. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current XSLT, you are getting the value of an element `a:string` within the `a:string` element. If you want to get the value of the current node, use a `.`

change your XSLT into this:

```
<xsl:template match="a:string">
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </test>
</xsl:template>
```